# I don't want warnings of Gmail ‘unusual sign-in location or device detected’ and I want to stop people attempting to sign in being blocked

Tags: gmail

I have a website about prisoners-of-war. People who had relatives who were POWs email me with details of their relatives and any queries they have, and I put the details on the website and try to help  with their queries.

I set up a special Gmail address for this purpose. However, as I get too many emails to be able to handle them all myself, I have a **number of helpers in several different countries**. I have given them the Gmail login and password.
However, they **get blocked by gmail and I get the `unusual sign-in location or device` warning. I want to disable this** – as far as I am concerned the helpers can use any location and device for this work. That’s my choice.

But I cannot find any way to disable this warning and blocking. Of course, it seems impossible to contact Google directly about this – I can only post this problem here and hope that someone can help. (It’s a pity that Google is so adamant that they do not want to help clients directly).

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

### Choice #1

Go to `Settings` > `Accounts and Import` > `Grant access to your account section`, click on `Add another account` and follow the steps.

> **WARNING**:
> Google may lock a Gmail account when used by too many people in different locations. [Share an account among users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33330)

### Choice #2

If as mentioned above you have too many users in your team or do not want to risk your account being blocked, you need to [Set up Gmail for your team](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172171)